# Python schedule a job until to the deadline

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, schedule

I am trying to schedule a job which works every X days to the deadline.

For example:

- Do this job in 2021 July 12 ~ 2021 August 9 for every 4 days.
- Do this job in 2021 July 15 ~ 2021 August 25 for every 3 days.

How can I do that with Python or Python modules?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scheduler library](https://gitlab.com/DigonIO/scheduler) for python to schedule a cyclic job with a start and stop datetime object.

```py
import datetime as dt
from scheduler import Scheduler

def spam():
    print("eggs")

delta = dt.timedelta(days=3)
start = dt.datetime(2021, 7, 12)
stop = dt.datetime(2021,8, 9)
    
schedule = Scheduler()

# schedule your job
schedule.cyclic(delta, spam, start=start, stop=stop, delay=False)
```

Execute job using a simple loop:

```py
import time
while True:
    schedule.exec_jobs()
    time.sleep(1)  # wait a second
```

Here you can find more [examples](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/quick_start.html).

*Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of the scheduler library*